# Old wallet.dat from 2016 with some btc not confirmed or in mempool

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

So I backed up a my bitcoin core wallet on an external drive back in 2016 and installed a new OS. I didn't really check on the wallet until recently and am having a bit of trouble getting the coins back. I downloaded the entire blockchain to the most recent Bitcoin core and the value has remained 0 throughout the entire process. Both of my receiving addresses reflect a 0 balance, when there should be about 1.5 BTC or so in the wallet. I have no idea what's going on but I will reward anyone who provides actionable information with 0.03 BTC

Comment: Has the client fully synced with the network (what is the output of `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo`)? Also, do you see any wallet history (past transactions), or is the wallet history blank?

Comment: In which folder did you replace the wallet.dat? Inside of your Bitcoin wallet default folder, it may have only three folders: blocks, chainstate and an other folder with the name of the wallet that you gave in the moment you opened Bitcoin Core, you should replace your wallet.dat inside of this folder.

Comment: How did you force Bitcoin Core to use your old wallet.dat? It may be necessary to restart Core if it was originally started without your wallet.dat (though I'm not sure).  You could also make a copy of wallet.dat and do some detailed inspection of the copy. See https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5025299.0